Python flask application is not working properly on Apache 24 in windows
I am using Python 3.8.10 with Apache(2.4.59) and mod_wsgi(4.9.4)on windows10. When running my application, the API requests go into a pending state. After troubleshooting with print statements, I found in Apache error logs that the issue occurs after importing pandas 2.0.3. How can I resolve this issue?
I have tried downgrading and upgrading the pandas version, but the issue persists.I even changed the version of python to 3.10.0 with necessary packages ,it didn’t work.
I want to run the application with 3.8.10 on Apache24 using mod_wsgi.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
